# Taking good free kicks

Tags: fifa-14

I have been playing fifa for a quite long time but am not able to score on free kicks. What is the best technique to a good free kick from about 40 yards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are awarded a free kick within 50 yards
before taking the kick try setting it up. This ia to be done by 
1) press the pace contol button so an extra player appers next to the 1st player 
2) now hold the pace control button and press the  short pass button, this will push the ball in front of a third player standing behind the two players you set.
Then this thrid player takes a shot after a small run to push the ball into the net.

Let me know if you would like to see a video.

Comment: It seems good. I would surely like to see a video.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qphyiv5p0wnxy30/VID_20140221_224133.m4v

Comment: Like it. Thanx fir your help.